# Magento collection filter where any attribute is empty

Tags: magento

I'm pulling a collection as follows

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('jan')
->addAttributeToSelect('name')
->addAttributeToSelect('upc')
->addAttributeToSelect('ean')
->addAttributeToSelect('price')
->addAttributeToFilter('ean', array('neq' => ''))
->addFieldToFilter(array(
    array('attribute'=>'type_id','eq'=>'simple')        
))
->setPage(1,5);
```

Currently I'm selecting all simple products WHERE 'ean' is not empty.  How can I select all simple products WHERE ean OR upc OR jan is not empty.

In other words select all products so long as the product has either an ean,upc or jan.  If they are all empty do not select it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento

```
class Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Collection_Abstract
```

-

```
class Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Collection_Abstract extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract
```

-

```
Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract

/**
 * Add attribute filter to collection
 *
 * If $attribute is an array will add OR condition with following format:
 * array(
 *     array('attribute'=>'firstname', 'like'=>'test%'),
 *     array('attribute'=>'lastname', 'like'=>'test%'),
 * )
 *
 * @see self::_getConditionSql for $condition
 * @param Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Interface|integer|string|array $attribute
 * @param null|string|array $condition
 * @param string $operator
 * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract
 */
public function addAttributeToFilter($attribute, $condition = null, $joinType = 'inner')
```

solution:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
array(
    array(
        'attribute' => 'ean',
        'neq'        => '',
        ),
    array(
        'attribute' => 'upc',
        'neq'      => '',
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'attribute' => 'jan',
        'neq'      => '',
        ),
    )
);
```